# I have a picturebox which shows the image captured by the camera.I want to send the captured image to the Api serve

Tags: c#-4.0

I want to send the camera captured image to the API server.For this i convert the image to the byte[].

```
private void Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       
        ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
        byte[] imageBytes = (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(pictureBox2.Image, typeof(byte[]));

        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
            client.UploadData("http://localhost:5000/api/upload/send", "POST", imageBytes);
            MessageBox.Show("Image successfully uploaded");
        }
    }
```

I try this but this is providing me the Exception System.Net.WebException: 'Unable to connect to the remote server'

Comment: Where is your API server hosted? localhost:5000 indicate that it is on the same machine as your C# application. Can you confirm if it's accessible on your the machine? You can perform tests using tools such as curl or telnet.

Comment: yes it is accessible